# Calculate the amount of time that a column was positive before reverting to 0

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetimeindex

I have a table containing non-negative values against a datetimeindex, like the following:

```
                    CapturableSeparation
date    
2021-02-23 18:09:00 0.00
2021-02-23 18:10:00 0.00
2021-02-23 18:11:00 0.04
2021-02-23 18:12:00 0.04
2021-02-23 18:13:00 0.00
... ...
2021-02-25 23:56:00 0.00
2021-02-25 23:57:00 0.91
2021-02-25 23:58:00 0.74
2021-02-25 23:59:00 0.55
```

I want to create a table of the amount of time between non-consecutive 0s (amount of time that positive values persist before reverting to 0) keyed with the average value of the "CapturableSeparation" during those consecutive positive values. For the data that is visible, the table might look like:

```
                    AvgValue
persistence 
00:02:00            0.04
00:03:00            0.73
```

where the first row corresponds to the positive values at the beginning of the Dataframe that persist for 2 minutes and the second row corresponds to those at the end that persist for 3 minutes.

How should this be done?

Comment: What have you tried so far? where have you failed?

Comment: @Manakin I initially tried creating a table with only the rows that contained positive values, then calculating time differences between observations. This caused too many leaps between the last consecutive positive and the next first, and I've struggled to come up with a conceptually sound solution that won't just brute force the problem. I could essentially do what I just said and remove all time differences over an hour, but that impedes the code's use for new data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of solving the problem by identifying the consecutive blocks of non-zero values using boolean masking and `cumsum`:

```
m = df['CapturableSeparation'].eq(0)
b = m.cumsum()[~m]
agg_dict = {'persistence': ('date', np.ptp), 
            'avgvalue'   : ('CapturableSeparation', 'mean')}

out = df.groupby(b, as_index=False).agg(**agg_dict)
out['persistence'] += pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
```

**Details:**

Compare the `CapturableSeparation` column with `0` to create a boolean mask:

```
>>> m

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
Name: CapturableSeparation, dtype: bool
```

Then use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) on the above boolean mask to identify the blocks of consecutive **non-zero** values:

```
>>> b

2    2
3    2
6    4
7    4
8    4
Name: CapturableSeparation, dtype: int64
```

Group the dataframe on these consecutive blocks and aggregate the column `date` using [`np.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) and column `CapturableSeparation` using `mean`:

```
>>> out

      persistence  avgvalue
0 0 days 00:02:00  0.040000
1 0 days 00:03:00  0.733333
```

Comment: When running the line "out = df.groupby(b, as_index=False).agg(**agg_dict)", I get a KeyError saying "Column 'date' does not exist". Is this because my date column is a datetimeindex?

Comment: yep you need to `reset` the `index` before using the above code.  check `df = df.reset_index()`